# Contraction mapping and $L^{2}(\Bbb R \times \Bbb R)$ spaces in inequality

Tags: normed-spaces, distribution-theory

I found this:

\begin{equation}
       \lVert Wx \rVert^{2}_{L^{2}( \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} )} 
       \leq \lVert x \rVert^{2}_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R} )},
            \end{equation}

which I think should be instead

\begin{equation}
            \lVert Wx \rVert^{2}_{L^{2}( \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} )} 
            \leq \lVert x \rVert^{2}_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})},
            \end{equation}

where $W$ like Wigner-Ville Distribution but Quadratic, so Quadratic nonlinear Time-Frequency Representation.

**In this context**

The signal $x : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Assume that $x$ is continuous, $x \in C(\mathbb{R})$, $x(t) \not= 0$ only if $a \leq t \leq b$ and that $|x(t)| \leq 1$ for all $t$, so the finite signal. 
Such signals span a dense subset $\mathbf D$ of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, and
            defining a mapping $W : \mathbf D \rightarrow L^{2}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$, for which the corresponding norm estimate
            \begin{equation}
            \lVert Wx \rVert^{2}_{L^{2}( \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} )} 
            \leq \lVert x \rVert^{2}_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R} {\color{red} \times \mathbb{R}})},
            \end{equation}
            which is $L^{2}$-energy of the signal $x : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ in the time-frequency plane $(t,f) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

**Is my thought right that the second one is right with $L^{2}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$ on the right-hand-side too?**

Comment: $\|x \|^2_{L^2(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})}$ makes no sense since $x \in \mathbf{D} \subset L^2(\mathbb{R})$, so it was ok before.

Comment: This one is correct :\begin{equation}
       \lVert Wx \rVert^{2}_{L^{2}( \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} )} 
       \leq \lVert x \rVert^{2}_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R} )},
            \end{equation}

Comment: Assume that we take $x \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$. **Is the first inequality still true?**

Comment: If we take $x \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ then we don't know what is the left-hand side, since the domain of $W$ is a dense subset of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ not the whole $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @Deyton Assume that we define too $W: L^{2}(\mathbb{R}) \to L^{2}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$. Is the first inequality still true in this case?

Comment: I cannot see any theorem there, you can define a contraction map (norm less than $1$) from $L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$, but you will loose the sense since you want to deal with signals and have $L^2$-energy of them.

Comment: Let $W \colon L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$ be such that for all $x \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ we have $\|Wx\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} \leq \|x\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})}$. Then $\|W\| \leq 1$, so $W$ is a contraction.

Comment: @Deyton Let $W: L^{2}(\mathbb{R}) \to L^{2}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$ be such for all $x \in C(\mathbb{R}) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$. The inequality then too: $||Wx||_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R})} \leq ||x||_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})}$. So a contraction map again, norm less than 1. **What do you mean by that we loose sense here when we are dealing with signals and have $L^{2}$ -energy of them?**

Comment: I opened a new question about the contraction map here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619823/why-contraction-map-bad-in-w-l2-mathbf-r-to-l2-mathbf-r-times-math because I did not understand why it is bad and why we loose sense in extending the domain to $L^{2}$.