# Contraction map in extending domain from Dense subset to $L^{2}$

Tags: normed-spaces, distribution-theory

This thread is about extending a dense domain $D \subset L^{2}$ into $L^{2}$.
I do not understand what Deyton means in [his comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614717/l2-bbb-r-times-bbb-r-spaces-in-inequality) about getting contraction map when doing this.

> I cannot see any theorem there, you can define a contraction map (norm
>   less than 1) from $W: L2(ℝ)→L2(ℝ×ℝ)$, but you will loose the sense since
>   you want to deal with signals and have $L^{2}$-energy of them.
>
> Let $W: L^{2}$(ℝ) → $L^{2}$(ℝ×ℝ) be such that for all x ∈ $L^{2}$(ℝ) we have ∥Wx∥$_{L2(ℝ)}$ ≤ ∥x∥$_{L2(ℝ×ℝ)}$. Then 
>   ∥W∥ ≤ 1, so W is a contraction.

where $W$ is like Wigner-Ville distribution but Quadratic.
It is quadratic nonlinear Time-Frequency Representation.

**Why should the value of the corresponding norm estimate stay in one?**
There is no exponent in the contraction map normally as $\leq (\cdot)^{2}$.

---

### Original situation

Take the signal $x \in L^{2}(\mathbf R \times \mathbf R)$.
Assume the domain can be extended to $L^{2}(\mathbf{R} \times \mathbf R)$ (from initially dense subset $D \subset L^{2}(\mathbf R \times \mathbf R)$ as domain)
\begin{equation}
W : L^{2}(\mathbf{R} \times \mathbf R) \rightarrow L^{2}(\mathbf{R} \times \mathbf{R}),
\end{equation}
and its corresponding norm estimate
\begin{equation}
\lVert Wx \rVert_{L^{2}( \mathbf{R} \times \mathbf R ) }
\leq \lVert x \rVert^{2}_{L^{2}(\mathbf{R} \times \mathbf{R})},
\end{equation}
which is a contraction map an the corresponding norm estimate less than one.

Comment: I think this question should be a comment of the previous question.

Comment: I disagree with you. It is impossible have formatting and such in a comment. Also, some people, who wanted to comment, did not have anymore power to comment. This was the only right decision to open a new question, like you see below.

Comment: For me, this discussion is not worth a question at all. This is all about an extension of a continuous map from a dense domain, which you can do as long as the map is uniformly continuous. But every comment, answer or similar raises more other unclear topics, because you do not specify precisely the context you are working in.

Comment: @Vobo I added an explanation what is $W$. It is like Wigner-Ville Distribution but Quadratic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to comment on your previous question, but I gave a 150 bounty and I lost the privilege to comment the questions.

First of all, I answered your doubts, that is, I said that, indeed, \begin{equation}(1) \ \quad
       \lVert Wx \rVert^{2}_{L^{2}( \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} )} 
       \leq \lVert x \rVert^{2}_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R} )} \ \ \forall_{x \in D},
            \end{equation}

is a correct condition since the domain of $W$ is $D \subset L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Then you asked me whether the above inequality is preserved if we take $x \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ instead taking it from $D$.

I don't know the references from which you wrote it up. I don't understand why you want to take $x \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, as you can see the domain of the map $W$ is $D$ so it may not be defined on the whole $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Thus, there might be such $x \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ for which $Wx$ does not make sense.

I mentioned contractions, but I didn't notice that there is no linearity assumption for $W$, the notion contraction for operators is rather used when we consider linear maps.

Further, $D$ is a set of all signals, so I guessed that in the context it is important to use them instead of ones which might not be signals.

### Possibility

But, if you use a linear map (consider $W$ to be linear) then the following theorem might be useful:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_linear_extension

**Theorem**

Every bounded linear transformation $\mathsf{T}$ from a normed vector space $X$ to a complete, normed vector space $Y$ can be uniquely extended to a bounded linear transformation $\tilde{\mathsf{T}}$ from the completion of $X$ to $Y$. In addition, the operator norm of $\mathsf{T}$ is $C$ if and only if the the operator norm of $\tilde{\mathsf{T}}$ is $C$.

Thus, if your $W$ is a linear map and the inequality (1) is true, we can extend it on the whole $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and the norm of the extension will be still less than $1$, so the inequality (1) will be also valid.

I hope that I was clear this time.

Comment: $W$ is not a linear map. You can assume it to be like Wigner-Ville distribution but Quadratic instead than linear.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, but it is not clear what you are writing. The norm of the operator makes sense only if you are in the space of linear bounded operators (or operator algebas). A linear map is a contraction if its norm is less or equal $1$, the norm in the space of bounded linear operators is given by $\|A\|= \sup_{x \colon \|x\| = 1}\|Ax\|$. Nobody would be able to help you if you were not clear, because a lot of things which you wrote does not make sense at all.

Comment: Sorry for confusions. I clarified the body of the question and removed comments which went already over this thread.

Comment: The norm of the nonlinear mapping is the corresponding norm estimate here.

Comment: I really recommend all to look at Grafakos book about Fourier Transform on $L^1 \cap L^2$, which explains this thing very well.